# Application crashes on screen rotate

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am implementing a progress dialog in a Thread. It works fine in landscape or portrait mode.
But when the device is rotated the application crashes and gives the following Exception:

**My androidMainfest.xml**

```
 <activity
        android:name="and.androidrest.Myactivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="standard" >
```

My Activity Code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sax_parser);
    callDialog(); 
}
public void callDialog(){
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait..");
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
    progressDialog.show();


    new Thread(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
            try{
                Thread.sleep(2000);           
            } 
            catch (Exception e){
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if(progressDialog != null){ 
                try{
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog=null;
                }
                catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }          
            }            
        }
    }).start();      
}
```

Here is my LogCat:

```
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309): Activity com.example.emailsending.SaxParserActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405217f8 that was originally added here
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.emailsending.SaxParserActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@405217f8 that was originally added here
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at com.example.emailsending.SaxParserActivity.callDialog(SaxParserActivity.java:157)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at com.example.emailsending.SaxParserActivity.onCreate(SaxParserActivity.java:52)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-04 09:54:53.825: E/WindowManager(1309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-04 09:54:53.906: D/dalvikvm(1309): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 107K, 52% free 2616K/5379K, external 910K/1038K, paused 66ms
03-04 09:54:53.995: D/AndroidRuntime(1309): Shutting down VM
03-04 09:54:53.995: W/dalvikvm(1309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View not attached to window manager
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.findViewLocked(WindowManagerImpl.java:355)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeView(WindowManagerImpl.java:200)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.removeView(Window.java:432)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:278)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.app.Dialog.access$000(Dialog.java:71)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.app.Dialog$1.run(Dialog.java:111)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-04 09:54:54.005: E/AndroidRuntime(1309):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: it's useful to post logcat also

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout` - unless you **really** understand why this is a hack and why you shouldn't do it, you should read the activity life cycle documentation and how and when to use onResume(), onPause(), onStop() and the other life cycle methods.  If you don't understand, then all you will do is hide the bugs because you haven't used the methods correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You are using progress dailog in activity . so when your rotate the phone then it will throw leakwindow exception.. for that you need to dissmiss progress at rotation time ...

Using this will solve your problem

```
@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();

    if(progressDialog != null)
    {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
```